# Fitbit and OAuth 2.0

Tags: ios, oauth, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, fitbit

I'm trying to add fitbit integration into an iOS app. I'm surprised to find how difficult this is... I imagined there would be an iOS SDK.

In any case, I'm trying to pull the data via the web-based API. It uses OAuth 1 & 2.

I've tried both, but have made more progress with OAuth 2.0.

I'm currently using **AFOAuth2Manager** to connect. Unfortunately, it is not working well.

Using the demo code with my account info, I get the following error:

> Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

By adding:

```
OAuth2Manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

That error goes away, but a new one is presented:

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow
>   fragments not set.

Here is the code I am using to make the request:

```
AFOAuth2Manager *OAuth2Manager =
        [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL
                                        clientID:@"CLIENT_ID"
                                          secret:@"CLIENT_SECRET"];

OAuth2Manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[OAuth2Manager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/oauth2/authorize"
                                          username:USER_NAME
                                          password:USER_PASSWORD
                                             scope:@"activity"
                                           success: ^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
    NSLog(@"Token: %@", credential.accessToken);
}
                                           failure: ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I wanted to try adding NSJSONReadingAllowFragments. But have been unable to get that into the code without error.

```
//OAuth2Manager.responseSerializer.readingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;
```

Comment: Having the same problem at the moment.

Comment: Could you please let me know, why and what are you using in USER_NAME and USER_PASSWORD?

Comment: The below link has sample code with fitbit framework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393507/fitbit-framework-is-available/34393522#34393522

Comment: Did anyone found the solution for this as I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Go carefully through https://appengineer.in/2016/04/30/fitbit-aouth-in-ios-app/ . You will get step by step solution and source code for FitBit integration

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I appended the wrong path to the Base URL. For example, my path was "/oauth/access_token."